# android convert ExternalStorageProvider to MediaProvider

Tags: android

I am having problems embeding local audio files into an ´` tag inside a WebView (I am using Ionic there). Everything works correctly if in the Chooser Intent the user selects the audio file from the MediaProvider (Audio shorcut) but If the user goes into their SDCard it breaks and I can not map it correctly on the WebView part.

For example with a file in SDCard -> Music

this is returned for SdCard:

```
name: "[MemoryCard] DragonBall GT - OP1 - Dan Dan Kokoro Hikareteku"
nativePath: "file:///sdcard/Music/[MemoryCard] DragonBall GT - OP1 - Dan Dan Kokoro Hikareteku.mp3"
uri: "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/326E-6BB3%3AMusic%2F%5BMemoryCard%5D%20DragonBall%20GT%20-%20OP1%20-%20Dan%20Dan%20Kokoro%20Hikareteku.mp3"
```

and this for the MediaProvider:

```
name: "Dan Dan Kokoro Hikareteku"
nativePath: "file:///storage/326E-6BB3/Music/[MemoryCard] DragonBall GT - OP1 - Dan Dan Kokoro Hikareteku.mp3"
uri: "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A14362"
```

So, I want to fix this on the Native Side handling the Chooser response and map the file from `com.android.externalstorage.documents` to `com.android.providers.media.document` but I can not find any way to do it, Is this possible?

Edit I am just converting the uri using a function of the webview framework https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/utilities#convertFileSrc. So, if I can map an SD card uri to an provider media uri it should work. Also, I am trying to support Android 6+

Comment: From the chooser you will get content scheme uries. It is unclear how you obtain a nativePath from it.

Comment: It is unclear why you would want to change the provider.

Comment: On Android Q+ a SAF uri can be converted to a MediaStore uri. And the other way round.

Comment: Further it is unclear what you want to embed in a tag inside a WebView

Comment: I am just converting it using a function of the webview framework https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/utilities#convertFileSrc. So, if I can map an SD card uri to an provider media uri it should work. Also, I am trying to support Android 6+

Comment: You have not answered my questions. Please do not refer to links but tell why you would convert anything.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what I haven't answered. My open question says that using the  external storage provider uri doesn't work webview audio src, so I want to map it to media provider because it works. The mapping to src is Javascript, it doesn't belong to the Java part. Or I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: I will post how the src is mapped as soon as I get to my pc.